# Apache: allow local connections to bypass basic authentication

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using HTTPS+basic auth (`AuthType Basic ... Require valid-user`) to protect a resource, but I'd like to allow connections from localhost through, even if they aren't authenticated.

What's the simplest way of doing that?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/33192/how-can-i-password-prompt-certain-ips-and-allow-all-others-free-access-using-apac

Comment: Oops, clearly my searching-foo failed me today. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can tell apache to allow connections from specific IP addresses, like this:

```
Allow from 192.168.0.1/24
Satisfy Any
```

If you add that to your authentication scheme it will allow any IP address in the 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254 range to access your content.

A full example may look like this (I am using digest, just substitute with your basic code):

```
<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    AuthName "SomeSite"
    AuthType Digest
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthDigestDomain http://somesite.com
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/password.file
    Require valid-user
    Allow from 192.168.0.1/24
    Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

Comment: Ah, 'satisfy' – that was the directive I was missing. Thanks!