# Allow from referer for HTTP-basic protected SSL apache site

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, authentication, http, https

I have an apache site protected by `HTTP` basic authentication. The authentication is working fine. Now I would like to bypass authentication for users that are coming from a particular website by relying on the `HTTP Referer` header.

Here is the configuration:

```
    SetEnvIf Referer "^http://.*.example\.org" coming_from_example_org
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Deny from all
            Allow from env=coming_from_example_org
            AuthName "login required"
            AuthUserFile /opt/http_basic_usernames_and_passwords
            AuthType Basic
            Require valid-user
            Satisfy Any
    </Directory>
```

This is working fine for `HTTP`, but failing for `HTTPS`. My understanding is that in order to inspect the `HTTP` headers, the `SSL` handshake must be completed, but `apache` wants to inspect the `<Directory>` directives before doing the `SSL` handshake, even if I place them at the bottom of the configuration file.

**Q: How could I workaround this issue?**

PS: I'm not obsessed with the `HTTP referer` header, I could use other options that would allow users from a known website to bypass authantication.

Comment: look at this may be help you fix the issues http://serverfault.com/questions/86401/apache-allow-local-connections-to-bypass-basic-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to improve your authentication mechanism quite a bit; given that the referer header is controlled by the client, I'd expect that it'll take someone about 18 seconds to work out what you're doing and bypass it.

The mechanism I would use would probably involve setting a cookie for your site that indicates that the user is "pre-authenticated".  Then you could test for the presence (and cryptographically valid) contents of that cookie in your apache config, and allow access that way.

Comment: @wombie: cookies are part of the `HTTP` headers, so in order to use your solution `HTTP` headers must be inspected before apache makes a decision on the `HTTP` basic authentication which it doesn't seem to be doing when using `HTTPS`. Therefore my question stands.

Comment: HTTP Basic auth is also part of the HTTP headers, therefore your theory is bunk.

Comment: it may be, but I know I can make this work with `HTTP` and not `HTTPS` so I still think it's related to the way `Apache` handles basic authentication vs `SSL` handshake.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an authorization script

ie. **mod_python** http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-handlers-auh.html

you can probably use something like this:

```
def authenhandler(req):
    if req.headers_in.get("referer") == 'yourhostname':
        return apache.OK
    pw = req.get_basic_auth_pw()
    user = req.user     
    if user == "spam" and pw == "eggs":
        return apache.OK
    else:
        return apache.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
```

the **mod_perl** can handle scriptable authentication and probably other languages too